# start/stop individual web app in tomcat using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

i have two web applications deployed on tomcat server using eclipse.

used the add and remove option to add the web applications to tomcat.

i want to stop one of my apps, how do i achieve this without stopping tomcat and removing the app manually.

start/stop option for individual webapp which we get on right click is disabled.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: unclear what is expected

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/

Answer (score 0):

You could access "Tomcat Web Application Manager" [IP/manager/html] page and undeploy the application.

Answer (score 0):

Use tomcat's manager webapp. 
Then if you have two webapps deployed, say app1 and app2, and want to stop app1, then use link like - 
http://localhost:8080/manager/text/stop?path=/app1

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Stop_an_Existing_Application